# Prove in triangle that 2OM=MH

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, triangles

Consider a triangle ABC. Let O be it's circumcenter,  M - it's center of mass and H it's orthocenter.

Prove that 2OM=MH.

I find this a little bit challenging, as there's no obvious - at least for me - connection between those three points. If someone would be able to direct me, I'd be grateful.

Comment: 1) The center of mass of a triangle is what point? Can you describe it using common 'special lines' in a triangle?

Comment: This is the [Euler line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line) in a triangle. See the wiki link for proof.

Comment: The Euler Line [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line)